# how to get the old filename of a file that's renamed in unix?

Tags: shell, unix

I've accidentally modified a script name XXX.sh to l.sh . And i should rename it from l.sh to the previous name it was with.

Can someone please help how i can get the old name that it was using.
thanks for your help

Comment: No way... But if something is dependant of this name, then it should be easy to find which name it was. Command history, other scripts, etc.

Comment: check your history file for the command you run for rename.

Comment: i did not run a command to rename it . I accidentally changed it through the GUI(winscp)

Comment: @karakfa please help me if there is a way

Comment: don't know about winscp,  but is there a log, what has it done on a server? if yes, you may have chance.

Comment: and who will call/execute the XXX.sh? if you find the caller script, you may find out the original name in the source?

Comment: Short form: There is absolutely not any generic cross-UNIX mechanism to do this. If you're using a filesystem that supports snapshots, and have regular snapshots created, then you might be fine -- but that's something your sysadmin staff can answer but we cannot.

Comment: perhaps you have snapshots from where you can recover?

Comment: Check winscp logs. Run history command on your shell - if the file was created recently, you may get the name. If the directory (where the file exists) is version controlled - you may get the original name from there.

Comment: Look on unix who is the owner. He might have created it. Ask him/her to look in the history or try to remember what it was.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. There is no snapshots saved for this. However we had a similar structure of it maintained on other server. I was able to compare both and get the file name.